# SEO friendly term syntax

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

I am writing a script that will pick a term from URL and pull the right data from my db based on that term.

So far I have added a line to my .htaccess file that will rewrite my URL into SEO friendly format, something like:

```
http://mydomain.com/catalogue/some-item-name
```

On the actual PHP page I grab that variable, strip dashes

```
$item= str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['item']);
```

and match the item to the hidden list on my page to pull the match with jQuery.

Everything works fine, unless I actually have a dash in the item name. My script removes all dashes. Shall I:

1. Replace actual dash into something else?
2. Find a way stripping just a single dash?

If i was pulling the term from db I could've used ***WHERE item LIKE "% $item %"*** but because I have to match to exact term alredy present in my HTML code, I'm kinda stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: Most sites work like stackoverflow (check the URL), so in short: `http://mydomain.com/catalogue/12345/some-item-nam ` and then you simply refer to the ID instead (so the text doesnt' matter at all).

Comment: Why don't you rewrite the URI as `http://mydomain.com/catalogue/ID/some-item-name` and use the (numeric) ID to get the item? This also works, if two items have the same name (or the same name after the name has been rewritten).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of doing that too, but before I do that I thought I'd try to figure out without using id.

Comment: @santa It depends on your application. If it's just a blog, you wouldn't want the ID in the URL because that would be counter-intuitive to direct linking. If it's a shopping thing or something else, links rot.

Comment: It's not a blog but somewhat of a reference app. I'd prefer to keep the URL clean and SEO-friendly. Currently I pull the item with jQuery using: $('#my_item').text(); Is there a way to make "fuzzy" match?

Comment: IMO it is always better to use id in URL as does the SO in its URL. You can have a full slug after it for SEO purpose.

Comment: @anubhava I can't really use ID because the items are already on the page, just hidden. I need to be able to match to the term, perhaps as close as possible. I can't modify the terms on the page, unless I loop through the list and format them in some way, perhaps stripping all spaces and dashes and making a unique camel cased term?..

Comment: @santa Couldn't you just add the ID to the elements as a data attribute? `<div data-id='123'>item</div>`;

Comment: But if I get my item as $item = "my item one" and the one I can potentially match it to is: "my item-one", how would Id help me?

Answer (score 1):

We use a system where we check the incoming URI against the database and see where to send the user. This way, we can completely detach the URI from the system internals (such as IDs).

We match the incoming URI against the `uri` field in the database and load the correct function from the correct class (controller) or redirects. It also has the option to send parameters to the function.

Let me show by example

```
+---------+---------+----------+----------+--------+
| uri     | class   | function | new_uri  | vars   |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+--------+
| faq     | support | faq      |          |        |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+--------+
| sandwich| content | news     |          | 1      |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+--------+
| banana  |         |          | sandwich |        |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+--------+
```

**Case 1:**
The user requests test.com/faq, the URI router finds a match on uri = 'faq' and tells the system to diplay whatever `faq()` in the support class or controller displays.

**Case 2:**
The user requests test.com/sandwich which is a shortcut for a news story with the ID 1. So the URI router sends a call to `news()` in the content class and we can retrieve the id 1 from a variable like `$_GET['vars'][0]`.

**Case 3:**
The user requests test.com/banana, which has been moved to test.com/sandwich since we are not in the banana industry anymore. So the URI router politely sends a 301 and redirects the user to the correct place.

This method has many ways to expand, e.g. by allowing wildcards in the uri field etc. Hope it can be of some value to you too.

Comment: But if I get my item as $item = "my item one" and the one I can potentially match it to is: "my item-one", how would this help me?

Comment: Well, you would have to make up some kind of rule set for how you would like the URLs to look. I've settled on stripping non-word characters and replacing all spaces with a dash. So first I do an initial replacement where I replace whitespace with dash and a few more special characters, then I do `preg_replace('/[^\w-]/i', '', $slug)`. The result is nicely readable URIs and should match as long as the rules don't change.